# Highmaps country map not showing when using type: "mappoint"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was working on India map demo in Highcharts, that have the following code:

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
    //type:'mappoint',
        map: 'countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed.js">India with disputed territories</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

It was working fine until I used `type: "mappoint"` .
I want to use `mappoint` type to dislplay points on the states of the country.
but using this mappoint type. my chart gets vanished and random points are showing on the screen.

You can see the example below in my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/5naocyqw/

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `mappoint` series, you have to specify the position of each point. 
You can do this by specifying the latitude and longitude. 
Remember to import the `proj4js` library in order to work with `lat` and `lon`.

```
 {
    type: 'mappoint',
    data: [{
      name: 'New Delhi',
      lat: 28.644800,
      lon: 77.216721
    }]
  }
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g49xcm7n/

Comment: is there no other way than that? i just need to show some mark on every state in the country

Comment: For showing single points in the map it's definitely the best method. There might be others, but not as effective as this one.

Comment: what about mapbubble ? it can do

Comment: A similar case. You also have to pass some position of the bubble centre.